# Wi-Fi выключен аппаратно и не включается. (Asus n751j, Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wifi, asus

На ноуте стоит Ubuntu 14.04 и Windows 10. Под Windows работает нормально. Когда загружаю линуху, Wi-Fi не работет и горит сигнал режима "в самолете". Fn+F2 не помогает.
lspci дает:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
```

ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:a0:50:8a:fb:de  
          inet addr:192.168.6.175  Bcast:192.168.7.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::56a0:50ff:fe8a:fbde/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:29197 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4193 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4946845 (4.9 MB)  TX bytes:661811 (661.8 KB)

lo        Link encap:Локальная петля (Loopback)  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1835 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1835 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 

 rfkill list
0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Но при этом, повторюсь горит индикатор режима полета. Железо исправно т.к. под виндой все работает. В BIOS все включено. Подскажите куда дальше двигаться, может кто то сталкивался с подобной проблеиой?

Answer (score 1):

Как стало ясно официальные драйвера немного хромые. Пройдите по ссылк, еслим читать с начала видно человек аж исследования целые провёл) Попробуйте, может поможет. Удачи!
http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=227100.msg1997608#msg1997608

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, буду разбираться. )

Comment: Надеюсь Вам поможет. Если да, пожалуйста, не забудьте отписаться здесь)

Comment: Заработало! Сделал все по инстркции. Только светится сигнал "в самолете", но Wi-Fi работает.